# detect swiping left on a cell in a tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to detect left swipe, so adding to my tableview at the start :

```
  //swipe left
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                         action:@selector(leftSwipe:)];
        [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
        [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

and then detect the cell itself with :

```
- (void)leftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

        CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       //show some menu in the cell position( its cell.frame)
}
```

It works only if the tableview is not scrolled down yet, that means after i scroll down, the detection position that i detect is wrong, hence if i try to add some side menu its not positioned right .

If i check this right at the start,without scrolling, it works great .

Why is that ?

Comment: SwTableviewCell implements a swipeable content view. This will help you to add swipes on cell https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. When i was adding the view, i put it in the view, not in the tableView, hence positions where wrong because they are calculate in relation to the scroller and not the view it self.

Adding the menu to the tableView,put it in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LazyTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        if (tableView == tableviewMsg)
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    else
    {
        for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews)
            [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    UIView *SwipeView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    SwipeView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,394,50);
    SwipeView.tag = -1001;
    [SwipeView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [SwipeView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:SwipeView];

        if([indexPath isEqual:indexSelected])
        {

            CGRect rect = SwipeView.frame;
            rect.origin.x = -45;
            SwipeView.frame = rect;
        }

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeGestureLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwipedLeft:)];
        [swipeGestureLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureLeft];


        UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeGestureRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwipedRight:)];
        [swipeGestureRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRight];



    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;

}
- (void)cellSwipedLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {


    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gestureRecognizer.view;
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tableviewMsg indexPathForCell:cell];


        if ([indexPath isEqual:indexSelected]) {


        }
        else{

            [self hideButtonForIndex:indexSelected animated:YES];

            [self showButtonForIndex:indexPath animated:YES];

        }

    }
}
- (void)cellSwipedRight:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gestureRecognizer.view;
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tableviewMsg indexPathForCell:cell];
        if ([indexPath isEqual:indexSelected])
        {
            [self hideButtonForIndex:indexSelected animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```